# Exporting a function to be runned at Console

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, export

A few days ago i found a code with something similar to this. There is no big deal at it, but a little thing interested me. It can be runned at the GoogleChrome Console.

As soon i serve the application with: 
**npm run local**

I can just go to the Console and type **SoundModule.playMusic();**

**"local": "node node_modules/rollup/bin/rollup src/client/main.js --o client/bundle.js --f es && node --max-old-space-size=8192 index"**

```
const SoundModule = {};

SoundModule.playMusic = async function(name) { .... };

export default SoundModule;
```

I'm really interested in how to write JS functions in my projects and run them using the Console, (since i don't know how to make it, i had to post a code snippet/node command)

Here it is the project that bough my question into life
https://github.com/johncintron/nodin

Comment: you can run any global client-side functions in the console. you can also access all global variables and their values

Comment: Not sure what you mean... The dev console runs in the global execution context (i.e. the `window`), so if you want to run a function it has to be available in the global namespace. Inside a module, you can accomplish this with `window.myGlobalFunc = function() { ... };`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet for making a function accessible in the `console` would be to attach it to the [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object:

```
window.myFunction = () => 'hello!'
```

[`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) is the global scope for the browser, and its properties can be referenced directly in the `console` without having to include the namespace, so you could simply type `myFunction()` in the console and it should return `"hello!"` to you.

Comment: This works pretty fine, i just edited the question with the original source code. The functions aren't at window, weird.. (but your answer is correct for this case)

Comment: Sure-- there are certainly other ways to ensure that a function is available in the browser console.  This solution is simply the most direct way to do it.  You could alternately assign the function to a variable you've declared w/o a `var`, `let` or `const` keyword, which will generally cause it to be raised to the global scope.  However, this may generate linting errors or be disallowed in [`"strict mode"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).  I'm not sure what drives its availability in your example-- it might even happen elsewhere in the code.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as solved, cause you're nailed